# How to use Composite Graph Plugin with external jtl or csv file?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

From the documentation of [CompositeGraph](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/CompositeGraph/) it is not clear how can an external JTL or CSV can be integrated?

> This listener will work only if you place it in your test plan before starting the test. If you add it after the test started or finished, the rows will not be displayed in the selector panel. This is valid also for csv / jtl file reload, you must add it before reloading files.

Now, coming to main part, how can I include external JTL or CSV in this plugin?

What I can understand from documentation is that, this Plugin only works when you run your Plan from GUI and enable this plugin before hand, this goes out of Best Practice of JMeter, we dont run our Performance Test from GUI.

Any help here....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the plugin, just mind the order of the Listeners being added, i.e.

1. Add Composite Graph
2. Add i.e. [Active Threads Over Time](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ActiveThreadsOverTime/)
3. Add i.e. [Hits per Second](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HitsPerSecond/)
4. Load `.jtl` results file into Active Threads Over Time
5. Load `.jtl` results file into Hits Per Second
6. You should be able to create a composite graph now

   [image]

More information: [How to Use the Composite Graph Plugin in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-composite-graph-plugin-in-jmeter/)